# esp32 reconnection after power surge

Tags: esp32

I have an esp32 as STA in my network, collecting sensor data, that publishes through my wifi AP to my home network. Everything was working fine until we had a general power surge in the neighborhood. When power came back the esp32 was out of the network. I had to recycle its power to let it re-establish connection. Is there an explanation for this? Most probably it came up much faster than the wifi or the mqtt broker did. Could this be the issue? If this is the issue, is there a way to postpone booting of the esp32 just after wifi network and mqtt is available?

Edit: I return to my original post to add some code that I used.

```
  void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  // Configures static IP address
  
  if (!WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, primaryDNS, secondaryDNS)) {
    Serial.println("STA Failed to configure");
  }
  
  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  ...
  client.setKeepAlive( MQTT_KEEPALIVE );
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.connect(aHostname);
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("mqtt status in setup: ");
    Serial.println(client.state());
    reconnect();
  } else {
    client.setCallback(callback);
    Serial.print("mqtt status in setup: ");
    Serial.println(client.state());
    client.setCallback(callback);
    client.setKeepAlive( MQTT_KEEPALIVE );
  }
```

Also if mqtt broker is lost there is a reconnection attempt in loop:

```
void loop(){
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a question of ESP32 booting faster than the WiFi access point, then this has a very simple solution. Retry the WiFi connection in ESP32 until it succeeds. Then do the same with MQTT. If you think about it, the device is useless without WiFi&MQTT connections so feel free to just keep retrying forever (or until it's successful).

In your case the MQTT broker's retry in the `loop()` should be an obvious example of to add a similar retry for the WiFi. Since I don't use Arduino and I don't currently have the time to read the WiFi module's documentation, I'll leave the implementation to you.

Comment: *Since you haven't posted any code or other relevant details, I can't help you with the specifics.* Which is why you should be voting to close the question. But it's off topic anyway as it's not even about programming. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: I agree that this question is of low quality by SO requirements. However, voting down is not productive. A discussion is productive. Hence, I will answer whenever I find it prudent to promote a discussion.

Comment: I edited my post and added some code. I retry to connect the wifi and broker, so it shouldn't be that.

Comment: I don't understand why this is an off topic question. I try to find an answer to an issue, it could be programming issue or some other thing. It is not so clear to me. Rob if it is clear to you please show the way.

Comment: @Tarmo *Discussion based questions are inherently off-topic for SO* https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288848/discussion-based-questions SO is a Q&A platform only.

Comment: @thermike Adding code may have improved your question but I don't have time to look at it right now.

Comment: @Rob - yes, correct. However, this is not a discussion based question. This is a reasonably specific question with a reasonably specific answer - just vaguely presented. Again, the productive thing to do is to poke the owner until that is fixed, so we can proceed to really answering the question.